# MySQL is returning an "column ambiguous" error when it used to work before I upgraded

Tags: sql, mysql

I recently upgraded MySQL to 5.1.41.  Before the upgrade the following SQL worked (or at least I thought I remembered it working...it has been a few weeks since designing this...).  Now the SQL gives me an error stating that the "archived" column is ambiguous.  How can I write this differently, or is there a different problem I'm not aware of?

I simply want to return the "unit_id", "lease_count" (stored in another table with a unit_id that should correspond with the "a.unit_id"), and "lease_archived_count (stored in another table with a unit_id that should correspond with the "a.unit_id").

```
SELECT a.unit_id, 
    (SELECT count(*) FROM o_leases WHERE unit_id = a.unit_id AND archived = 0) as lease_count, 
    (SELECT count(*) FROM o_leases WHERE unit_id = a.unit_id AND archived = 1) as lease_archive_count

FROM p_unit a, properties b, portfolio c 

WHERE a.property_id = b.properties_id 
AND b.portfolio_id = c.portfolio_id 
AND a.archived = 0
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is archived a column in more than one of your tables (p_unit, properties, portfolio)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can only be one place where this error is referring to. I suggest to give the tables in the sub select also an alias:

```
(SELECT count(*) FROM o_leases o WHERE o.unit_id = a.unit_id AND o.archived = 0) as lease_count, 
(SELECT count(*) FROM o_leases o WHERE o.unit_id = a.unit_id AND o.archived = 1) as lease_archive_count
```

It seems that it collides with the `archived` field of `p_unit`.

Comment: Thanks felix! I found the root of the problem ended up being the wrong column in the table (I had a hardrive crash last week and I loaded the wrong table).  But your syntax was what I should have used in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the error is because o_leases is not the only table that has an archived field.  p_unit Or properties or portfolio must have that column as well.

However you have several other things that should also be fixed. First in most databases correlated subqueries are poor performers and should be rewritten as joins (although in this case you probably only need a case statement and a join). You should notgenerally even consider writing correlated subqueries.

Second, you should NEVER use implicit joins. Extremely bad idea that leads to poor maintainability and accidental cross joins as well as a generally poor understanding of joins. Bad bad bad. This kind of code was replaced 18 years ago, would you still be using C# or Java code relaced witha better method even five years ago?

Comment: Thanks Hlgem.  To be honest, I was taught years ago to join tables this way and it's worked for me ever since.  Performance wise, I haven't seen much difference between the two and I haven't found many articles that say one is better than the other.  However, your point regarding accidental cross joins I agree with.  My mind naturally understands the implicit syntax better probably because of my early coding days.  Nevertheless, if any newbie's out there read this...I agree with learning the newer explicit syntax in the event you create a cross join and don't know it you will be notified.